# URL Rewrite PHP .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I do not know how i can code the .htaccess file to make it rewrite a URL like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/one/two/three?four=five&six=seven
```

into this:

```
http://www.domain.com/RequestHandler.php?path=one/two/three&four=five&six=seven
```

I am not sure if this even possible, if it is impossible tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /RequestHandler.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```